# Is it possible to perform shell injection through a read and/or to break out of quotes?

Tags: bash, security

Consider this example of (attempted) shell injection:

test1.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
read FOO
echo ${FOO}
```

z.dat:

```
foo && sleep 1 && echo 'exploited'
```

Then run:

```
cat z.dat | ./test.sh
```

On my machine (Ubuntu w/bash) the payload is always (correctly) treated as a single string and never executes the malicious sleep and echo commands.

Question 1: Is it possible to modify z.dat so that test.sh is vulnerable to injection?  In particular are there specific shells that might be vulnerable?

Question 2: If so, is changing the test script to quote the variable (shown below) an absolute defense?

test2.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
read FOO
echo "${FOO}"
```

Thanks!

Comment: This makes for good reading: [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)

Comment: *Is it possible to modify this example so it is vulnerable to injection?*  Yes, put `eval` at the front of the `echo`:  `eval echo ${FOO}`.  Then you get what you deserve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not according to: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/OpenSource/Conceptual/ShellScripting/ShellScriptSecurity/ShellScriptSecurity.html

Search for 'Backwards Compatibility Example'

Comment: Good reference.  Points out another injection attack I hadn't considered: if [ x$FOO...